# Selenium on heroku DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So, I'm trying to deploy a node, selenium app to heroku.
This is how my code looks

```
let options = new Options();
options.setChromeBinaryPath(process.env.GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN);
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-usage");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");

options.setUserPreferences({"prefs":{"useAutomationExtension": false}});
    let serviceBuilder = new ServiceBuilder();
    console.log("initialized serice builder");
    let driver = new Builder(process.env.CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH)
    .forBrowser(Browser.CHROME)
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .setChromeService(serviceBuilder)
    .build();
```

This throws an error on the heroku logs like so

```
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372134+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:517
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372174+00:00 app[web.1]: let err = new ctor(data.message)
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372175+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372176+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372176+00:00 app[web.1]: WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372177+00:00 app[web.1]: (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372180+00:00 app[web.1]: (The process started from chrome location /app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372181+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.throwDecodedError (/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:517:15)
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372181+00:00 app[web.1]: at parseHttpResponse (/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:642:13)
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372181+00:00 app[web.1]: at Executor.execute (/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:568:28)
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372182+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372182+00:00 app[web.1]: remoteStacktrace: '#0 0x5630d5f6be89 <unknown>\n'
2021-05-18T05:42:15.372183+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-05-18T05:42:15.465529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-18T05:42:15.532468+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Nothing seems to fix the issue, I've added the required buildpacks, and have also checked all the versions. Also note that this code runs perfectly fine on my local machine. I saw a similar question where the user manually added the DevToolsActivePort file, but that doesn't seem to be possible as I can't ssh into the heroku server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: exactly samething here.. local works.. but on ubuntu server headless it doesn't.. any clue?

Comment: nope :/ I'm thinking of rewriting the entire thing using puppeteer, but I'm too lazy, and hope I can fix this somehow

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass in a flag to disable Chrome Devtools Sandbox, so it will no longer look for `DevToolsActivePort`. It is also recommended to `disable-gpu` with a headless webdriver:

```
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
```